# Compare two hash arrays in ruby except a key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hash arrays like this:

```
hashArray1 = [{"id"=>"1","data"=>"data1"},{"id"=>"2","data"=>"data2"}]
hashArray2 = [{"id"=>"3","data"=>"data1"},{"id"=>"4","data"=>"data2"}]
```

I want to compare both of them and return true if everything else matches without the "id" key.

I have tried something like this:

```
hashArray1.each do |h1|
  hashArray2.each do |h2|
    if h1.select{|h| h!= "id"} == h2.select{|b| b!= "id"}
      break
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

But this seems to be incorrect. Does anyone have a better solution. I am on plain ruby 1.9.3, not using rails framework.

Comment: Your variable name `hash1` and `hash2` are misleading. They are not a hash.

Comment: @sawa point noted, hope its fine now. The question has already been answered though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
hash1.zip(hash2).all? do |h1,h2|
  return false unless h1.keys == h1.keys
  h1.keys.each do |key|
      return false if h1[key] != h2[key] unless key == 'id'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If `hash1.length != hash2.length` then you can bail out immediately as they can't be the same. If they have the same length then you could do something like this:

```
except_id = ->(h) { h.reject { |k, v| k == 'id' } }
same = hash1.zip(hash2).find { |h1, h2| except_id[h1] != except_id[h2] }.nil?
```

If `same` is `true` then they're the same (while ignore `'id'`s), otherwise they're different. Using [`Hash#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-reject) is one pure Ruby way to non-destructively look at the Hash without a particular key. You could also use:

```
except_id = lambda { |h| h = h.dup; h.delete('id'); h }
```

if "copy and remove" makes more sense to you than filtering. If you don't like [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) then [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) might read better:

```
same = hash1.zip(hash2).all? { |h1, h2| except_id[h1] == except_id[h2] }
```

or even:

```
same_without_id = lambda { |h1, h2| except_id[h1] == except_id[h2] }
same == hash1.zip(hash2).all?(&same_without_id)
```

Comment: I liked your answer too, but since @hirolau answered almost the same thing first, so accepting it, but an upvote for you. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not necessarily clear, but I assume the order of the hashes are taken into account.

```
hash1.map{|h| h.reject{|k, _| k == "id"}} ==
hash2.map{|h| h.reject{|k, _| k == "id"}}
```